# Submit transaction with cardano-cli which got built and signed with nodejs-cardano-wasm - formatting error

Tags: cardano-cli, node

I am trying to submit a transaction via cardano-cli which got built and signed by a nodejs app using cardano-wasm. I tried the following approach:
[image]

The result I get from the cardano-cli execution:

> error: Command failed: cardano-cli transaction submit --tx-file /tx-files/tx.signed --mainnet
>
> Command failed: transaction submit Error: Failed to decode neither the cli's serialisation format nor the ledger's CDDL serialisation format. TextEnvelope error: /tx-files/tx.signed: TextEnvelope aeson decode error: Error in $: Failed reading: not a valid json value
>
> TextEnvelopeCddl error: /tx-files/tx.signed: Could not JSON decode TextEnvelopeCddl file at: /tx-files/tx.signed Error: Error in $: Failed reading: not a valid json value

Besides *txToSubmit.to_bytes()* I have also tried to write the tx-file with content of *txToSubmit.to_json()* and *txToSubmit.to_hex()*

But I get the same result.

Does anyone know in which format the tx-file has to be and how to get it there? Submitting via Blockfrost "txSubmit(txToSubmit.to_bytes())" works flawlessly, but I want to switch to cardano-cli :)

**EDIT:**
I figured out, that the tx.signed file has to be in a similar format like this:

```
{
    "type":"Witnessed Tx ShelleyEra",
    "description":"",
    "cborHex":"xxx(cbor-built-by-cardano-wasm)"
}
```

(Is the type "Witnessed Tx ShelleyEra" even correct for submitting signed transactions on mainnet?)

Could someone provide me a sample tx.signed file?

When submitting the transaction via cardano-cli (**cardano-cli transaction submit --mainnet --tx-file /tx-files/tx.signed**) I receive the following error:

> Command failed: transaction submit  Error: Failed to decode neither the cli's serialisation format nor the ledger's CDDL serialisation format. TextEnvelope error: /tx-files/tx.signed: TextEnvelope type error:  Expected one of: TxSignedByron, TxSignedShelley, Tx AllegraEra, Tx MaryEra, Tx AlonzoEra, Tx BabbageEra Actual: Witnessed Tx ShelleyEra
>
> TextEnvelopeCddl error: /tx-files/tx.signed: TextEnvelopeCDDL CBOR decoding error: DecoderErrorDeserialiseFailure "Shelley Tx" (DeserialiseFailure 1 "Size mismatch when decoding \nRecord RecD.\nExpected 4, but found 3.")

**EDIT2**:

Okay its working now :)
I played around with cli and created a new address, supplied it with ada, built and signed a transaction and thats what I got:

```
{
  "type": "Witnessed Tx BabbageEra",
  "description": "Ledger Cddl Format",
  "cborHex": "xxx (cbor)"
}
```

I was able to submit a transaction with this code:

```
const txToSubmit = CardanoWasm.Transaction.new(signedTransaction.body(), keyWitness, undefined);
const tempTxName = '/tx-files/tx' + Math.round(Math.random() * 99999) + '.signed';
fs.writeFileSync(tempTxName, JSON.stringify({
            type: 'Witnessed Tx BabbageEra',
            description: 'Ledger Cddl Format',
            cborHex: txToSubmit.to_hex()
        }));
exec('cardano-cli transaction submit --tx-file ' + tempTxName + ' --mainnet', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
    return;
  }
  if (stderr) {
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```